# Small change in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[marks_581](
[Name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[Subject] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[Marks] [int] NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO marks_581 
select 'Dishant','English',40 union all
select 'Dishant','Maths',45 union all
select 'Dishant','Hindi',49 union all
select 'Pranay','English',41 union all
select 'Pranay','Maths',45 union all
select 'Pranay','Hindi',50 union all
select 'Gautham','English',41 union all
select 'Gautham','Maths',45 union all
select 'Gautham','Hindi',49 

select * from marks_581

And my output should be like the below one

Name |Subject1|Marks1|Subject2|marks2|Subject3|marks3
Dishant|English |40 |Maths |45 |hindi |49
Gautham|English |40 |Maths |45 |hindi |49
Pranay |English |40 |Maths |45 |hindi |49
```

This is my query and I am not able to get the subject name in subjects column. It says like couldn't convert varchar to datatype int. Any anyone help me?

```
SELECT Name,       
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'English' THEN Subject ELSE 0 END) AS Subject1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'English' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks1,        
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Maths' THEN Subject ELSE 0 END) AS Subject2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Maths' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks2,    
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Hindi' THEN Subject ELSE 0 END) AS Subject3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Hindi' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks3 
FROM marks_581
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: You can't `SUM` a subject name.. it's not logical, and it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different aggregate function, such as `MAX()`, for non-numeric data:

```
SELECT Name,       
    MAX(CASE WHEN Subject= 'English' THEN Subject END) AS Subject1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'English' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks1,        
    MAX(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Maths' THEN Subject END) AS Subject2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Maths' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks2,    
    MAX(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Hindi' THEN Subject END) AS Subject3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Hindi' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks3 
FROM marks_581
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Although, given the nature of this query, we know we can simplify it further:

```
SELECT Name,       
    'English' AS Subject1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'English' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks1,        
    'Maths' AS Subject2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Maths' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks2,    
    'Hindi' AS Subject3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Hindi' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks3 
FROM marks_581
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name,       
    MAX(CASE WHEN Subject= 'English' THEN Subject ELSE Subject  END) AS Subject1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'English' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks1,        
    MAX(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Maths' THEN Subject ELSE Subject  END) AS Subject2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Maths' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks2,    
    MAX(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Hindi' THEN Subject ELSE Subject  END) AS Subject3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Hindi' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks3 
FROM marks_581
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: You're still going to need an aggregate, What does it do when it has to group `'Maths', '', and ''` into 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of ...

```
 THEN Subject ELSE 0 END
```

... subject is varchar not int

Answer (score 0):

Hey what i feel is the mistake is here

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[marks_581](
[Name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[Subject] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[Marks] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

The table created using above commands will not have sub1 sub2 sub3 and mark1 mark2 and mark3

Comment: He never `SELECT`s `mark1`, `mark2` and `mark3`. He only `SELECT`s `Mark` and `Subject` which do exist, then he names the columns `Mark1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name,       
'English' AS Subject1,
SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'English' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks1,        
'Maths' AS Subject2,
SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Maths' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks2,    
'Hindi' AS Subject3,
SUM(CASE WHEN Subject= 'Hindi' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Marks3 
FROM marks_581
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```